# Apple Mach-O Librarian (libtool) Error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am running a React-Native iOS app and I am getting the following errors when I build within XCode.  What could be the issue?

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lBVLinearGradient
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lBVLinearGradient is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the linker can't locate the library:

```
libBVLinearGradient
```

> You follow the readme, all steps? You did the step 2, 3 and 4
>   correctly? After you import in Xcode project the file
>   **libBVLinearGradient.a** is in Products folder.

↳ https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/20

Comment: I am using CocoaPods to do this.  So I didn't do those steps.